# High current traces (up to 60 A) routing problem

Tags: pcb, pcb-layers, high-current, trace

I need to design a power inverter that might have up to 60 A of current flowing through the leg IGBTs and still could not figure out the best way out for that amount of current. The DC bus voltage may reach 311 V.

Cost restrictions do not allow me to choose \$ 2\,\text{oz}/\text{ft}^2\$ from the manufacturer, thus I must stick to \$ 1 \,\text{oz}/\text{ft}^2\$ (\$35\,\mu\,m\$) of copper thickness. I am concerned about temperature rise since I'll be using FR4 and thus up to \$ 20º\,\text{C} \$ might seem a bad idea. The board shall have 4 layers which I have not decided the low current/low voltage signal paths yet.

The figure below depicts the attempts I went for to reach the target 60A current capability.

[image]

The upper sector (connector J11 is a 3 mm in diameter hole with pad shape 7 mm) depicts a screw terminal connector and a Hall-effect sensor as both PTH pads that I chose to design a filled zone in **both top and bottom** as a means to withstand as much current as possible. \$\textbf{Is that a good idea? Else, what should I do?}\$

The following figure shows the **4 mm (158 mil)** trace routed on both top and bottom as well.

Again, **is there a better way out so as to have a clearer design for the 60 A current path?**

[image]

Last but not least, the following figure illustrates the lower sector, which I have again filled a zone on both top and bottom to help improve current capability.

[image]

**Is there a proper way to route these tracks bearing in mind that it needs to withstand 60 A as well as not overheating?**
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd use parallel copper connections on up to all for layers

Comment: Open the soldermask and you'll get free solder to significantly thicken your track?

Comment: @Andyaka I see, thank you. The inner layers however are set to 0.5 oz/ft^2, which I intend to leave as far as possible from any digital/analog circuitry.

Comment: @IronMaiden yeah, so? There's not going to be any circutry running between your Power connectors, right? If there's any significant current that would be running on the inner layer through that point, it would be actually *better* noise-wise to run it elsewhere. Your argument hence doesn't hold!

Comment: @winny Indeed, I might even use additional cables not to leave solder exposed.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes I see that, I was just pointing out that I would of course leave these tracks far from other current paths as common practice. I might've expressed myself badly.

Comment: @IronMaiden Oh, please excuse my irritated tone! So, yeah, use all layers, add solder to thicken top and bottom, make sure there's enough copper surface in the environment to act as heat sink

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's ok, don't worry ! Thank you for your input. I will try to make those tracks even wider to help boost heat exchange and route them on all layers

Comment: Even if you use all 4 layers it will need a lot of trace width to get to 60 A with only 10 C temperature rise. Example: with 1/0.5 oz planes: 2x 8mm traces on top and bottom gave me 16 A current capability, and 2x 8mm traces on inner layers only add a bit less than that - so to go 60A you either need to drop your +10 °C target, or use wider traces, or use thicker copper, or add some copper foils or bars. I'd used [Saturn PCB Toolkit](https://saturnpcb.com/saturn-pcb-toolkit/)... maybe you must do all of that together to get up to 60 A